# My For Statement Is Displaying My HTML Page Multiple Times Instead Of Just Once

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to go through an HTML page and replace each numbered CampaignID and add a div tag with a number and z-index to highlight each link. The for statement is replacing each div tag with the next CampaignID 1-10 but it is printing out 10 of the same HTML page with each having the next numbered CampaignId and div tag replaced. I just need one page with each "a href" numbered on the page. What do I need to change in this code to make that happen? I would put the output for you to see but it is too much HTML code.

```
using (SqlConnection connection =
                       new SqlConnection(con))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                
                string CampaignId = reader["CampaignId"].ToString();
                string htmlCreate= reader["ConvertedCreative"].ToString();
                StringBuilder strContents = new StringBuilder();
                for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                {

                    string replacement = "<div style=\"z-indexer:1;background:#0c538e;width:2.25em;height:2.25em;text-align:center;color:white;\">" + i + "</div><a href=\"http://www.trackingstats.info/Process.aspx.c=/" + CampaignId + "&l=" + i + "\"";
                    Regex regex = new Regex("<a href=\"http://www.trackingstats.info/Process.aspx.c=24896&l=" + i + "\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    string result = regex.Replace(htmlCreate, replacement);
                    strContents.AppendLine(result);





                }
                Label1.Text = strContents.ToString();
            }
           
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your issue correctly, it sounds like you need to move the line `strContents.AppendLine(result);` outside of your for loop. You are adding the result text to the StringBuilder each time through the loop, which would equate to 10 times.

In fact, if you don't want to duplicate it 10 times, you shouldn't need the StringBuilder.

Perhaps something like this?

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    string replacement = "<div style=\"z-indexer:1;background:#0c538e;width:2.25em;height:2.25em;text-align:center;color:white;\">" + i + "</div><a href=\"http://www.trackingstats.info/Process.aspx.c=/" + CampaignId + "&l=" + i + "\"";
    Regex regex = new Regex("<a href=\"http://www.trackingstats.info/Process.aspx.c=24896&l=" + i + "\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    htmlCreate = regex.Replace(htmlCreate, replacement);
}
Label1.Text = htmlCreate;
```